# Constructing a linear map given its minimal polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

> Let $\mathbb{R^3}$ be our vector space and over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Given that its minimal polynomial is $x^3-x^2$ construct a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R^3}$.

---

**My thoughts**

Since $m_T(x)=x^2(x-1)$, we deduce that $T$ must be upper triangularisable and also $\chi_T(x)=-m_T(x)$. So I construct such $T$ based on the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R^3}$ so that $T(e_1)=0$, $T(e_2)=0$ and $T(e_3)=e_3.$

**My doubts**

Is this a viable method to approach this problem? Is there a quicker way to approach this question?

Also what can we do if the minimal polynomial is less than the degree of our vector space? Is there an algorithm-ish that I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $T$ you suggest is diagonal(isable) with respect to the standard basis, and its minimal polynomial has simple roots.

The easiest way to build a solution is to think in terms of Jordan forms. Here you should expect two blocks, $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{1}$.

In general if the degree of the minimal polynomial is less than the dimension of the domain, it simply means that some eigenspaces are of dimension larger than $1$, and therefore that there is more than one Jordan block for the same eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of a polynomial $p$ has $p$ as both its minimal and its characteristic polynomial. This gives a systematic solution when the degree of $p$ equals the dimension of the space.